# php if - is it so memory intensive?

Tags: php, memory-management

Just now I was running scripts with preg_replace, over large set of datarows, I had this line of code:

```
$words = array("http", "www", "com", "org", "related", "cache", "asp", "php", "html", "wid", "roomid", "wmaster", "pcash", "sdk", "vippath");
foreach ($words as $seek):  
    if ($row['title'] = preg_replace("/(\S*)$seek(\S*)/i", "",$row['title'])):
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Now, when I ran this over 1000 rows, I would get memory_limit error, however, when I changed the code to this:

```
$words = array("http", "www", "com", "org", "related", "cache", "asp", "php", "html", "wid", "roomid", "wmaster", "pcash", "sdk", "vippath");
foreach ($words as $seek):  
    $row['title'] = preg_replace("/(\S*)$seek(\S*)/i", "",$row['title']);
endforeach;
```

I was able to run it on 40,000 rows and not hitting the memory limit...

Anyone has any insight on this?

Edit:

```
if ($res = parent::dbDelta("SELECT id, title, used FROM " . databaseConn::TITLE_TABLE . " LIMIT 40000, 0", true)):
$query .= "INSERT INTO tmp (title, used) VALUES ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)):
$fail = false;
    $words = array("http", "www", "com", "org", "related", "cache", "asp", "php", "html", "wid", "roomid", "wmaster", "pcash", "sdk", "vippath");
    foreach ($words as $seek):  
            $row['title'] = preg_replace("/(\S*)$seek(\S*)/i", "",$row['title']);
    endforeach;

    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $row['title'], $matches); 
    $numbers = $matches[0];
    $numbers = array_map('intval', $numbers);  
    foreach ($numbers as $num):
        if (($num > 100) &&  ($num != 365) && ($num != 247) && ($num != 360) && ($num != 1800) && ($num != 800) && ($num != 1900) && ($num != 900)):
            $fail = true;
            $row['title'] = str_replace("$num", "",$row['title']);
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if ((str_word_count($row['title'])) < 3):
        $fail = true;
    endif;

    if (!$fail):
        $row['title'] = trim($row['title']);
        $query .= "('$row[title]', '$row[used]'), ";
    endif;


$i++;
endwhile;
        $query = substr(trim($query), 0, -1);
        $query .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE used='0'";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
endif;
}
```

Comment: The `if` is pointless there - the condition is always checked anyway.

Comment: I know it is, I was just wondering.

Comment: Are you sure this is all you got? Maybe there is a decisive loop outside this looping?

Comment: You did something terribly wrong. 1000 rows are plain nothing ans shouldn't cause memory issues.

Comment: yes, encased in a while loop, but it doesn't matter, as when I removed the 'if' it was able to run over large record sets.

Comment: @Itai: Then please post your whole code, the clue might lie somewhere in it ;)

Comment: What happens if you make the assignment (-> $row['title'] = preg_replace(..);) first, and then test the result later on (-> if($row['title']){})

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$words = array("http", "www", "com", "org", "related", "cache", "asp", "php", "html", "wid", "roomid", "wmaster", "pcash", "sdk", "vippath");
$regex = "/(\S*)".implode('|',$words)."(\S*)/i";
$row['title'] = preg_replace($regex,"",$row['title']);
```

Comment: it's a nice answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with your if statement is that it is setting a variable instead of comparing it.